# How to send swift selector reference to objective c property

Tags: objective-c, swift, performselector

I have property `@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL buttonSelector` in objective C class which have button to show thing

```
- (void)setUpBarButton:(id)vc {
    UIBarButtonItem * optionsItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Options"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:vc action:buttonSelector];
    optionsBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0);

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[self.optionsItem];
}
```

So from swift class i am using above method so i have to send selector refrence from swift class

```
self.buttonSelector= #selector(tapbutton:)
```

but its give an error

Answer (score 0):

Your code is so buggy. There are three button variables:

```
optionsItem
self.optionsItem
optionsBarItem
```

Why even have a selector variable? Just handle any different cases in the selector!